# Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters ocur in alphabetical order

Tags: java, methods

I'm learning programming online with Java. I know expressions, variables, if statements, iterations, static methods, arrays, switches, and other basic things. I'm currently struggling with an assignment involving writing methods right now, if I could get some help it would be great.

Here it is:

**Problem:** Assume s is a string of lower case characters. Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh
```

In the case of times, print the first substring. For example, if s = 'abcbcd', then your program should print

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc
```

Here's what I have so far:

- put the letters of String s into an array as individual letters
- for loop scans through array for longest substring in alphabetical order

```
static String problemThree(String s){
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            
        }
        return s;
    }
```

I'm not sure what to do next or where to start with this problem.

Comment: `Java` and `Javascript` are different languages. Also if you ask for help without providing any code yourself, the learning effect is much smaller than providing your code and telling us where you are stuck.

Comment: These questions are not language specific, you also need to learn how to solve problems using pseudocode. You should learn to solve problems first, understand algorithms and then code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder where Problem 1 is.

**Problem 2**:
That is a completely wrong usage of `switch`. What you are doing is to compare string `s` with `"bob"` and see if they are equal. An alternative of your wrong approach is

```java
if ("bob".equals(s)) answer++;
```

The more cases, the more strings you are checking equality between `s`.

A correct approach is to make use of the `String.indexOf(String, int)` method, which returns you the index of the given string in the original string, if exists, starting at the index you specified.

For example,

1. `"abcbobabc".indexOf("bob", 0)` returns 3.
2. `"abcbobabc".indexOf("bob", 3)` returns 3.
3. `"abcbobabc".indexOf("bob", 5)` returns -1. (cannot find)

Reminder: the first index is 0.

After finding the first appearance, start searching from the next index so the "first appearance" will be the next one, if exists, instead of the one we found.

1. `"bobob".indexOf("bob", 0)` returns 0.
2. `"bobob".indexOf("bob", 1)` returns 2.
3. `"bobob".indexOf("bob", 3)` returns -1.

But we only want to count to appearance, not to return the indices of appearance. Hence, here is the code:

```java
if (s == null) return; // prevent NullPointerException
int i = 0;
int count = 0;
while ((i = s.indexOf("bob", i)) != -1) {
    i++;
    count++;
}
return count;
```

**Problem 3**: Java does not have a method to directly scan for substrings in alphabetical order, so you will need to implement it yourself, by scanning character by character.

Firstly, the alphabetical order of any two characters can be compared with the inequality sign, only if both are together either upper case or lower case.

```java
String longest = "";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
// for storing character streak in alphabetical order

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i); // Access the character at index i in the string given.
    int length = builder.length();
    if (length == 0 /* no streak */ 
        || Character.toLowerCase(builder.charAt(length - 1)) <= Character.toLowerCase(c)
        /* has streak, and the new character has alphabetical order greater than 
the last one e.g. z greater than a */) {
        /* starts or continues the streak */
        builder.append(c);
    } else {
        /* stops the streak */
        if (length > longest.length()) {
            /* new streak is higher than the last one, so replace it */
            longest = builder.toString();
        }
        /* either streak is not high enough or not, resets the streak */
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
return longest;
```

Basically the entire code is to

1. Loop through all characters
2. Keep adding characters that are in alphabetical order to the string builder
3. If the next character does not follow the order, stop the streak
4. See if the string built by the builder is longer than the last one

Answer (score 0):

For problem 2, you can loop from the start of the string and take  substring = 3 char of string e.g. azc, zcb until the list[length - 3] (3 = length of "bob"), and forever time substring.equals("bob") count ++.

For problem 3, have a placeholder String longestString = "".
Run a for loop for each letter in the string, define currentString = "", run another for loop from current index onward, append the letter to currentString if alphabetic order (look up for String.compareTo()), once you reach a letter not in alphabetic order, check if currentString is longer than longestString -> longestString = currentString.

Answer (score 0):

for problem 2 I'd personally save an index i and increment s.length() times, substring at i, checking whether substring begins with "bob".

for problem 3 save an index i and increment s.length() times, substring at i, save an index j and increment substring.length() times, save a char last, comparing substring.charAt(j) to the last character, if it occurs later in the alphabet than the last character or they are the same append the character to a String built and update the last character, finally if built.length() > longest.length() update longest to built

```
    private static int problemTwo() {
        String s = "azcbobobegghakl";
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.substring(i).startsWith("bob")) {
                count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    private static String problemThree() {
        String s = "azcbobobegghakl",
                longest = "";

        // Increment i s.length() times, i determining how far into the string we start at e.g. if i is 5 substring will be "bobegghakl"
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String substring = s.substring(i),
                    built = "";
            char last = 0;

            // Increment j substring.length() times
            for (int j = 0; j < substring.length(); j++) {
                char c = substring.charAt(j);

                // If the last character occurs earlier in the alphabet or the same as the current character, append it to the built string, and update the last character to be the current
                if (last <= c) {
                    built = built.concat(Character.toString(c));
                    last = c;
                } else {
                    // Break out of the for loop if the current character occurs earlier in the alphabet than the last
                    break;
                }
            }
            
            if (built.length() > longest.length()) {
                longest = built;
            }
        }

        return longest;
    }
```